# QTableModel data not being called

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a custom table model that extends `QAbstractTableModel`. I've implemented `data()`, `rowCount()` and `columnCount()`.

This is my model:

```
point_data_view_model::point_data_view_model(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

int point_data_view_model::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
   return 2;
}

int point_data_view_model::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /*parent*/) const
{
    return 3;
}

QVariant point_data_view_model::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
       return QString("Row%1, Column%2")
                   .arg(index.row() + 1)
                   .arg(index.column() +1);
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

But when I want to show the table view in my form, nothing is displayed.

This is the form's constructor:

```
SelectWindow::SelectWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
    ,ui(new Ui::SelectWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);

    point_data_view_model  myModel;

    ui->tableView->setModel(&myModel);
    myModel.timerHit();
   ui->tableView->show();


}
```

In other words, my data function in the model is not called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
point_data_view_model  myModel;
```

That's a big problem. `myModel` is local to that constructor and will get destroyed when the function exits. You need to store that model somewhere that persists as long as you need to use it - a member variable of your `SelectWindow` should be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating `myModel` on stack. It gets deleted immediately after calling `ui->tableView->show();`. So the view loses the model and doesn't have a chance to call `data`. You should create `myModel` using `new`:

```
point_data_view_model* myModel = new point_data_view_model();
```

Comment: Careful with leaks: the view won't delete the model, so you need to handle that yourself.